# Как выполнить LINQ запрос к списку IList<Object>?

Tags: list, объекты, linq

Есть описанные в LINQ две MS SQL таблицы "AvWork" и "Channel".
Есть код. В нем я анализирую какие изменения (updates) были выполнены в таблице «Channel»:

```
IList<Object> canUpdStat = dataAvZVKDataContext.GetChangeSet().Updates;

foreach (Object j in canUpdStat)
   {
     if (j is Channel)
        {
         ....           
        }
   }
```

Можно ли через LINQ выполнить подобный запрос?
Такая конструкция не работает:

```
var test = canUpdStat.Where(x => x.Channel);
```

Перерыл кучу ссылок в Инете, но не нашел, как сделать.

Comment: Вместо Object указывайте точный тип.

Comment: Попробуйте var test = canUpdStat.Where(x => x.GetType() == typeof(Channel));

Answer (score 2):

Для этого существует отдельный метод расширения `OfType<T>`, который фильтрует по принадлежности к классу. Код для вашего примера:

```
var test = canUpdStat.OfType<Channel>();
```

Answer (score -1):

Конструкции:

```
    var test = canUpdStat.Where(x => x.GetType() == typeof(Channel));
var test = canUpdStat.OfType<Channel>();
```

прекрасно работают. Спасибо!
Как преобразовать test к типу IEnumerable(Channel) или другому типу, который поддерживает GroupBy()? Конкретный тип нужен для передачи в функцию.